# Confused about "Using $this when not in object context" fatal error

Tags: php, oop, this, fatal-error

I searched around on stackoverflow about the "Using $this when not in object context" but I could't get my answer out of it so I ask it here.

I will just copy my code here so you and me dont get confused:

the error is in this code on the first IF statement($this->checkConnection()):

```
public function randomLocation() {
        if ($this->checkConnection()) {
            $fetch = array();
            $character = $this->getCharacter($_GET['action']);
            $locations = Controller_Core_Database::getObjects('Model_Game_Location');
            foreach ($locations as $location) {
                $fetchLocation = $location->getLocationNameShort();
                $fetch[] = $fetchLocation;
            }
            $newLocation = rand(0,31);
            $character->setLocation($fetch[$newLocation]);
            Controller_Core_Database::update($character);
        }
    }
```

But I have many functions that begins with this 'checkConnection' and those work, except for this one. which is strange in my opinion(although i'm still a beginner with OOP PHP)

so this is my checkConnection function:

```
public function checkConnection() {
        $mysqli = Controller_Core_Database::getDB();
        if ($mysqli != null) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

the Controller_Core_Database::getDB() code is:

```
public static function getDB() {
            self::$mysqli = new mysqli('','','','');
            return self::$mysqli;
        }
```

I have remove the information for security purposes.
And here is a example of a function that works **perfectly**:

```
public function createItem() {
        $view = new Controller_Core_View();
        $view->setViewFile("game/createItem.php");
        if ($this->checkConnection()) { 
            $item = Controller_Core_Database::getObjects('Model_Game_Item');
            $enchantment = Controller_Core_Database::getObjects('Model_Game_Itemenchantment');
            $view->assign("item", $item);
            $view->assign("enchantment", $enchantment);
        }
        return $view->render();
    }
```

I dont see any different between the 2 functions that works and not works, 
I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specified, how **randomLocation()** method is called.

I supose you are calling that non-static method staticaly - thats why you are not in an object context.

If so, consider rewriting either call to **randomLocation()** method to use object context - e.i.

```
$x = new YourObjectName();

$x->randomLocation();
```

or rewrite **checkConnection()** method to be static and call it staticaly in **randomLocation()** method.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me and its stupid I didn't know this.